# Connect a mysql table to a web page

Tags: mysql

I have a website setup and published. In this website there is the usual Contact Us page with relevant fields to be completed.
I have a mysql database set up with a table called contactus.

My question is;  how do I connect the contact us page with the table to record the information as put in on the web page, I also need the information emailed to me.

Following is the code on the contact us web page which shows code for the fields.

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="content_item">
      <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <p><CENTER> WE ARE HAVING PROBLEMS WITH OUR CONTACT PAGE. PLEASE USE OUR EMAIL ADDRESS TO CONTACT US UNTIL THIS PROBLEM HAS BEEN FIXED.</CENTER></p>
      <p>Please complete this form by providing as much information as possible:</p>
      <div style="width:170px; float:left;"><p>Name</p></div>
      <div style="width:430px; float:right;"><p><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_name" value="" /></p></div>
      <div style="width:170px; float:left;"><p>Email Address</p></div>
      <div style="width:430px; float:right;"><p><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_email" value="" /></p></div>
      <div style="width:170px; float:left;"><p>Message</p></div>
      <div style="width:430px; float:right;"><p><textarea class="contact textarea" rows="8" cols="50" name="your_message"></textarea></p></div>
      <br style="clear:both;" />
      <p style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0;">Please enter the answer to this simple maths question (to prevent spam)</p>
      <div style="width:170px; float:left;"><p>Maths Question: 9 + 3 = ?</p></div>
      <div style="width:430px; float:right;"><p><input type="text" name="user_answer" class="contact" /><input type="hidden" name="answer" value="4d76fe9775" /></p></div>
      <div style="width:430px; float:right;"><p style="padding-top: 15px"><input class="submit" type="submit" name="contact_submitted" value="Send"><a href="mailto:driveoffuk@gmail.com"></a>
      </p></div>
    </div><!--close content_item-->
```

I would appreciate and help with this.

Comment: that's basically what PHP is for, and there's a gazillion examples of basic html/php/database interactions all over the web.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be more explicit. You don't "connect" HTML code to a database table.

What technology are you using for the backend? PHP? nodeJS? rails? (or others) Do you want this call to be asynchronous?

Actually you may want to have a script in the backend where you send the form info (by the way, you should have that code as a HTML form) and from the script you can manipulate the information and store it to the database.

If you are more specific about what technologies you are using, I can help you better!